# Is is possible to block push notifications from other applications while running my Unity app?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, push-notification, virtual-reality

I'm running a VR app in Unity and would like to silence push notifications to the screen while it's running. I'm using Parse right now for push...
Is this possible, or does Apple not allow this?

Comment: I don't think the system will allow you to do so...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this is not allowed.

But, if you have control of the device (for example using a demo device) you can use **Guided Access** to restrict the features available during use of your app.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202612

[image: guided access ended]